# Why dynamically created HTML Input is Empty After Postback

Tags: asp.net, html, dynamic

I add HTML  and  tags to Page dynamically.
But after every postbost, all values are empty.
What can I do for Solve?

Comment: Can you give an HTML / code example?

Comment: Code is Very Long.
Part OF HTML Code:

string HTMLCode = "<input name="txtValue_15" id="idtxtValue_15" type="text" runat="server" style="width: 150px;" />";

//Literal is in Page.
lit.Text = HTMLCode;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the controls you add to the page have an ID, and that the ID is the same after posting back.

Comment: Won't work for him. As far as I understood, he creates them with Javascript.

Comment: No, I create HTML control ASP.NET Code Behind.
I get from string and show in Literal.
Literal fill in Page_Load.

Comment: Dont work with ID.
I can get value of HTML control a button click but after all values go on empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create controls in Init event of page, creating controls in Page_Load will not retain viewstat because according to control lifecycle, controls must be created before load event and just before load, the controls retrive their viewstat information. Create a new event Page_Init (make sure you write Init="Page_Init" in your first line in the Page tag). And create your controls in this event.

Comment: Sorry but it dosnt work.
Dynamically created Asp.Net Controls works fine but HTML tags dont works.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep the values after postback in this case, use Request.Forms[key]

you will get key-value pair here. You must prepare input in certain fix format like name attribute comes first then value etc. Then as you know format you can put back value filed in Page_load. User regular expression to replace string with pattern.

```
string UpdatedText = Label25.Text;

foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (key.ToLower().StartsWith("recomandedspec_"))
    {
        string keyvalue = Request.Form[key];
        // this uses regular expression to replace input string with postback values
        UpdatedText = PreFillItem.FillTextBox(UpdatedText, keyvalue, key);  
    }
}

Label25.Text = UpdatedText;
```